# akka http with actors : error 503 timeout

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I m trying to implement AKKA http and some actors on Scala.
I created a web app with akka.
But i have this error on one or 2 differents routes /16. (it s apparently random ) :

> The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request.
>   Please try again in a short while!

Could you explain to me why and how to fix it?
I m really novice with Akka.

The Main class :

```
object WebServer extends App {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("app-1")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
    val routes = SessionRoute.route
     val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(routes, ipServer, configApplication.getInt("spray.can.client.proxy.http.port"))
    println("serv http launch")
    StdIn.readLine
    bindingFuture
        .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
        .onComplete(_ => {
        cluster.close()
        system.terminate()
    })
    bindingFuture.onFailure {
        case ex: Exception =>
            println(ex, "Failed to bind to {}:{}!", ipServer, configApplication.getInt("spray.can.client.proxy.http.port"))
    }
    }
```

My route is :

```
object SessionRoute extends TokenValidator {
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

val sessionHandler = WebServer.system.actorOf(SessionHandler.props(), "SessionHandler")
implicit val timeout = Timeout(60.seconds)


val route: Route = get {
    authenticated(doAuthPublisher) { app =>
         getActiveUserPublisher 
    }
}
def getActiveUserPublisher =
    path("session" / JavaUUID / "active_user") { publisher_id =>
        parameters('date_start.as[Long], 'date_end.as[Long]) {
            (date_start, date_end) => {
                onSuccess(sessionHandler ? SessionActiveUser(SessionRequest(publisher_id, date_start, date_end, null))) {
                    case response: Answer =>
                        complete(StatusCodes.OK, response.result)
                    case _ =>
                        complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, "Error on the page")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My Actor is :

```
    object SessionHandler {
        def props(): Props = {
            Props(classOf[SessionHandler])
        }
    }
    class SessionService(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends toolService {
     def activeUser(sessionRequest: SessionRequest): Map[String, Any] = {
    ....
      }
    }

class SessionHandler extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("session")
    implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

    def receive: Receive = {
     case request: SessionActiveUser =>
     sender() ! Answer(Serialization.write(new SessionService().activeUser(request.sessionRequest)))
    }}
```

And my case class used :

```
final case class Answer(result: String)
case class SessionActiveUser(sessionRequest: SessionRequest)
case class SessionRequest(publisher_id: UUID = null, date_start: Long, date_end: Long, app_id: String = null)
```

My configuration.conf :

```
    akka {
  loglevel = INFO
  stdout-loglevel = INFO
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  default-dispatcher {
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 8
    }
  }
 // event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you see is caused by your `route` not being able to produce a response within the configured request-timeout. If you haven't explicitly set it, it defaults to 20 seconds. See [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/timeouts.html#request-timeout) for more info on the request timeout.

About the cause of this happening, could you detail what happens in the `activeUser` function? Any significant blocking happening there? If so, all your incoming requests will be sequentialized and blocked against `activeUser`, eventually causing the request timeouts to kill your requests.

Possible solutions are:

- make your service async/non-blocking
- follow the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html) on how to deal with blocking calls inside Akka-HTTP routes